# specific program mpd for live streaming

Tags: streaming, live, mpeg-dash, mpd

I am trying to dash my live video streaming and also saving them to be able to watch them later on my website. it is working for 1 hour timeshift. but i need to make mpd for a specific program, not limited by hour. and to separate my programs, make a list and have an mpd for each. for example each football game must have one mpd. how can I do this?

edit:

I am using nginx to make dash files, like this:

```
  application dash {
  live on;
  dash on;
  dash_nested on; # this work but not separate the variant mpd 
  dash_path /dev/shm/dash;
  dash_fragment 2; # 2 second is generaly a good choice for live
  dash_playlist_length 120; # keep 240s of tail
  dash_cleanup on;
  dash_variant _low bandwidth="256000" width="320" height="180";
  dash_variant _med bandwidth="832000" width="640" height="360";
  dash_variant _hi bandwidth="1024000" width="1024" height="576";
}
```

and the source video:

rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

Comment: Simply *do that*?  Not sure what else to tell you without knowing what software you're using or anything.  How is it set up now?  Simply change your configuration.  Simply add other streams.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg and mp4box to make dash files @Brad

Comment: What does your script look like for this?  Where's the source video even coming from?  Add this information to your question.

Comment: @Brad I added the information